# Authentication and authorize, djangorestframework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a problem with django rest framework token-based authentication. I can create user, but his password not hash, then I wrote implementation of method `create` in my serializer. This didn't worked. Only root can receive token and his password is hashed. Even user receive a Token. Code here:
https://github.com/XxXAsmoXxX/DjangoBlog
Authorization and authentication in folder `restapi`, folder with settings `tasks`

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ ...
I am using a create function like this in my serializer. It sets the password hashed if you were using django User model.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        username=validated_data['username']
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```